# Need to verify address of a user in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, mkmapview

I need to verify the address entered by user in my app .What basically i need is how to veriry the address entered by the user suppose user enters the address like 7 Breezeland Road, Carpentersville, IL - 60110  now this is the correct address  for which i can get lat lon from the following google api http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=7 Breezeland Road, Carpentersville, IL - 60110 .

But suppose say user enters 7  asdfasdf  Breezeland Road, Carpentersville, IL - 60110 then i need to verify this type of address, means is there any api  for the same which i can prompt user that this is probably wrong address and ask him was he looking for this 7 Breezeland Road, Carpentersville, IL - 60110.

If someone can add their inputs or suggestions or any related API it would be a great help .

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to be excited about the Google Geocoding API: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Answer (score 1):

Jordan's on the right track with the Google API, but note that Google does address *approximation*, not address *verification*. For actual (USA) address validation, you'll need to access a CASS-Certified vendor (one who has been approved by the USPS) to supply official information.

I used to work in the address verification field, at SmartyStreets. For example, they have a service called LiveAddress - it's free like the Google API, but will only return *correct* results and suggestions, among many other things. So look into that... remember, you probably are wanting to determine if an address is actually deliverable. That comes from official USPS data. Google will show you a pretty map and make a best guess, but often the addresses don't actually exist.

Comment: hi @Matt , you are correct. I am also using smartystreets , if user enters wrong address what will be the results?